# How to checkout folder into existing project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have existing project in eclipse and I want to checkout another repo/folder via svn into that particular project. Eg:

I have a project `xyz` and I want to checkout repo `MessageSpecs` from some svn location. I tried to simply do import>svn checkout but it marks that particular checked out `MessageSpecs` folder as project. Though it checks out the project but in eclipse view I see two different `MessageSpecs` one which is marked as a project and another in my project directory although both are same as I do any changes in either of location it reflects into other one.

But my goal is to make one so that I can avoid any kind of ambiguity and work flawlessly. Pleas see attached image for more clearance

[image: demo image]

```
PS: I am using subclipse for check out purpose and my eclipse IDE is Neon
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is your can't.

Subclipse does not support checking out a repository as a subfolder of another.  Repositories can only be checked out as top-level projects.

However, SVN itself offers a feature that would allow you to do this in a different manner and Subclipse supports this feature.  It is called svn:externals and is documented in the SVNBook here:  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html

So let's assume you wanted this MessageSpecs folder to be a folder in the root of the project you checked out from some other repository.  What you would need to do is define the svn:externals property on the parent folder for your project with a value like this:

```
http://svn.example.com/repos/MessageSpecs/trunk MessageSpecs
```

You set this property on the folder and commit it.  Then whenever you checkout or update this project it will also update and pull in this other folder.  In your case, since you would just need to do the update once you set this property and it will process the svn:externals property to checkout this other project.